# Which directory is ansible looking for when it makes an SSH connection?

Tags: linux, ssh, ansible, windows-10

This situation is for Linux Ansible master and a Windows target.

When I run:

```
ansible all -vvv -u myuser -m ping --ask-pass
```

ansible -vvv tells me:

```
<aloysius> (1, b'', b'The system cannot find the path specified.\r\n')
<aloysius> Failed to connect to the host via ssh: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I note that it wants to have:

```
ControlPath=/home/admin/.ansible/cp/5803c98fce
```

and this directory, "5803c98fce", does not exist on the ansible host. (At least before and after running):

```
ansible all -vvv -u myuser -m ping --ask-pass
```

First, is ansible saying that it's "ControlPath" does not exist on the Linux master?

```
ControlPath=/home/admin/.ansible/cp/5803c98fce
```

or is it talking about this one I assume should be on the remote host (which btw yes this directory does exist on the remote host although it is Windows...):

```
echo ~/.ansible/tmp
```

I really  can't tell what this means which might've helped:

```
 (1, b'', b'The system cannot find the path specified.\r\n')
```

.

.

Also note that on the win target, my functioning-otherwise ssh user does in fact have ownership of the ~/.ansible/tmp==~.ansible\tmp directory:

```
you may have been able to authenticate and did not have permissions on the target directory.
```

Here's the complete -vvv output:

```
[barney@bigstack ~]$ ansible all -vvv -u myuser -m ping --ask-pass
ansible 2.9.13
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/admin/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.6.8 (default, Apr 16 2020, 01:36:27) [GCC 8.3.1 20191121 (Red Hat 8.3.1-5)]
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
SSH password:
host_list declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
script declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
auto declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
Parsed /etc/ansible/hosts inventory source with ini plugin
META: ran handlers
<aloysius> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: myuser
<aloysius> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d9 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'User="myuser"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/admin/.ansible/cp/5803c98fce aloysius '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~myuser && sleep 0'"'"''
<aloysius> (1, b'', b'The system cannot find the path specified.\r\n')
<aloysius> Failed to connect to the host via ssh: The system cannot find the path specified.
<aloysius> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: myuser
<aloysius> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d9 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'User="myuser"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/admin/.ansible/cp/5803c98fce aloysius '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo "`pwd`" && sleep 0'"'"''
<aloysius> (1, b'', b'The system cannot find the path specified.\r\n')
<aloysius> Failed to connect to the host via ssh: The system cannot find the path specified.
<aloysius> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: myuser
<aloysius> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d9 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'User="myuser"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/admin/.ansible/cp/5803c98fce aloysius '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo ~/.ansible/tmp `"&& mkdir "` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1603723134.4556515-646377-252845712428430 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1603723134.4556515-646377-252845712428430="` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1603723134.4556515-646377-252845712428430 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
<aloysius> (1, b'', b'The system cannot find the path specified.\r\n')
<aloysius> Failed to connect to the host via ssh: The system cannot find the path specified.
aloysius | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to create temporary directory.In some cases, you may have been able to authenticate and did not have permissions on the target directory. Consider changing the remote tmp path in ansible.cfg to a path rooted in \"/tmp\", for more error information use -vvv. Failed command was: ( umask 77 && mkdir -p \"` echo ~/.ansible/tmp `\"&& mkdir \"` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1603723134.4556515-646377-252845712428430 `\" && echo ansible-tmp-1603723134.4556515-646377-252845712428430=\"` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1603723134.4556515-646377-252845712428430 `\" ), exited with result 1",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

Please kind stacks, you're our only hope.

Comment: just a guess, but is `sshpass` installed on the linux box?

Comment: @TomH No sshpass installed

Comment: `The system cannot find the path specified.` is a Windows error message. Whatever is happening is on the Windows host, not the Linux controller. At a guess I'd say Windows doesn't have a `/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 0):

The [ping](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/ping_module.html#ansible-collections-ansible-builtin-ping-module) module works only with Linux and BSD targets. For Windows targets use the [win_ping_module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_ping_module.html).

Comment: win_ping works over WinRM, not over ssh.